# Problems building in release mode with Teamcity

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

We have a TeamCity project for building our .NET applications, using MSBuild as the build runner.
This works fine for debug applications, but fails when building in release mode.

The error in the log is as follows:

```
[13:45:51][Step 1/1] MSBuild command line parameters contain "/property:" or "/p:". It is recommended to define System Property on Build Parameters instead.
[13:46:21][Step 1/1] Publishing artifacts
[13:46:21][Publishing artifacts] Collecting files to publish: [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\43d8c20fca7ef208\BuildScripts\RetainedPlanner\..\..\Build\Release\RetainedPlanner\..\*.msi]

[13:46:21][Step 1/1] Failed to publish artifacts: External scan (outside of basedir) is not allowed

[13:46:32][Step 1/1] Publishing artifacts
[13:46:32][Publishing artifacts] Collecting files to publish: [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\43d8c20fca7ef208\BuildScripts\RetainedSMS\..\..\Build\Release\RetainedSMS\..\*.msi]
[13:46:32][Step 1/1] Failed to publish artifacts: External scan (outside of basedir) is not allowed
```

I am setting release build by either a build parameter (/p:Configuration=Release) or as a config option in TeamCity, they both have the same result.

The release build step is an exact copy of the debug build step except that I have changed the artifact path to be `Build/Release/**/*.msi` instead of `Build/Debug/**/*.msi` and set the config option for release mode.

This build step used to work, and has remained unchanged since Sept 2013. It was not run since then until now, and it now fails. The only differences are that I have updated the teamcity server to be server 2012, and team city itself has been updated to v9. I am unable to roll TeamCity back as it doesn't support this.

I have (of course) tried googling the error message, but nothing relevant can be found.

I have verified that the path exists.

I am not even clear where this error is being generated from - MSBuild?
We are using the MSBuildCommunityTasks including Wix, I've searched the .target files and cannot find this error message anywhere (or anything similar).

If anyone has any light they can shed on this, as we are stumped.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the problem was? Just ran into the same error.